# Comparing elements in HasMap with List as a value

Tags: java, dictionary, stream

I'm trying to do some exercises but I don't want to use if statement because program will be to long. I have a List people where:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private Integer score;
    private Group team;
    private boolean active;
}
```

and

```
public enum Group {
    G1, G2, G3
}
```

My job is to find a Group where Person have highest score but if score from two groups are the same I have to return group where there is more inActive people. If number of inActive player is the same doesn't matter which group I return.

I group everything in Map

```
Map<Group, List<Person>> collect = people.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getTeam));
```

and than create two other map where I group scores and inActive people.

```
for (Map.Entry<Group, List<Person>> entry : collect.entrySet()) {
    collect1.put(entry
            .getKey(), entry.getValue().stream()
            .mapToInt(Person::getScore).sum());
    collect2.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().stream()
            .filter(p -> !p.isActive())
            .count());
}
```

How can I compare now to get result like in task.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the aggregates in two separate maps, I'd go for objects grouping the aggregated results. Something like

```
class GroupStats {
    private Group group;
    private int score;
    private int activePlayers;
}
```

I omitted the constructor and getters for brevity here. Then you can do something like

```
    collect.entrySet().stream().map(e -> {
        Group group = e.getKey();
        int score = e.getValue().stream()
                .mapToInt(Person::getScore).sum();
        long activeCount = e.getValue().stream()
                .filter(p -> p.isActive())
                .count();
        return new GroupStats(group, score, activeCount);
    }).max(Comparator
            .comparingInt(GroupStats::getScore)
            .thenComparingLong(GroupStats::getActivePlayerCount))
    .ifPresent(stats -> System.out.println(stats.group));
```

Comment: I was thinking about to do something like this but I cannot add any new class, just to create method using this what I have.